# Filtering entity sets at data model level

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a scenario where I would like to filter some entity sets at model level, not at query level, i.e. I basically want to 'hard code' the filtering into my model, so that I don't always have to repeat the same Where method filtering in every query against an entity set.  More specifically, I have a `CampaignTypes` entity set, and in the data model I am busy with I only want campaign types belonging to a certain business area.  Without the lower level filtering I seek, every time I query `CampaignTypes` I will have to use `CampaignTypes.Where(ct => ct.BusinessArea == BusinessAreas.Outdoor)`.  How can I avoid this repeated filtering short of creating a DB view and using that in my model instead?

Comment: Have you figured this out?  I'm facing the same problem as you did @profk

Comment: @MussaMoses See the accepted answer. That is the only way I could find, is to use query methods as my data source instead of directly using the DbSets

Comment: Thank you @ProfK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<CampaignType> getCampaignTypes()
{
    using (var context = new TestEntities())
    {
        var campaignTypes = context.CampaignTypes.
            Where(ct => ct.BusinessArea == BusinessAreas.Outdoor).
            AsQueryable<CampaignTypes>();
        return campaignTypes;
    }
}
```

Use the result of this method, instead of accessing context directly.  You can also modify your query to return a list, set, etc. by changed the "AsQueryable" method to "AsList", etc.

Comment: just a tip:  I've learnt to not use 'using' blocks like this for EF queries.  It gets in the way of lazy loading because when a client tries to access a navigation property not yet loaded, EF may  try and load it and find the context already disposed, and throw you a rude exception.

Comment: Thanks, ProfK.  I'm lot using lazy loading, so wasn't aware of this.  I'll take a closer look this evening (at work right now) and figure out if I should delete my answer, or modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another layer (a logical layer) between the code that doesn't need to worry about the filter and the entity set.  This layer can return an IQuerable or whatever and it would apply the filter to the entity set and return the results.

That way the other parts of your application wouldn't have to worry about applying this filter and it is still a single query (for most cases) that is executing against the database.

Comment: Yes, I have often done this before in my Service layer, but I was just curious as to any 'closer to the metal' approaches.

Comment: There may be.  I would avoid anything that has you changing generated code, since it will be overwritten as soon as you regenerate the code.  Even in my simple applications, I have a middle tier, even if it is just a thin logical tier, as it is usually needed at some point in time.

Answer (score 1):

you can create another property with a different name in another file,
 extending the main partial class of your model.

**EDIT:**

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    using System.Data.Objects;

    public partial class SomeModelEntities
    {
        public ObjectSet<CampaignType> FilteredCampaignTypes
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_CampaignType == null))
                {
                    _CampaignType = base.CreateObjectSet<CampaignType>("CampaignType");
                }
                return _CampaignType.Where(ct => ct.BusinessArea == BusinessAreas.Outdoor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "duplicate it with a different name in another file", but I don't like to change generated code, especially in early development as I re-generate the model quite often.